# Turning text with # symbols into links in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, twitter

I was wondering how would I do the following using Javascript.

Suppose I had a text like the following

```
var test = '#test is a #cool #place';
```

and I want the following

```
<a href="abc.html?q=test">#test</a> is a <a href="abc.html?q=cool">#cool</a> <a href="abc.html?q=place">#place</a>
```

How would I do that?

Comment: This is doable, but bit messy in JS. If you're dealing with large amount of such conversions, consider a client side templating engine like [Jade](http://jade-lang.com) or [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com).

Comment: This should be a comment imo.

Comment: Just earned enough repo to add comments, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally like this better:

```
stringToMatch.replace(/(<a[^>]*)?#(\w+)(?!\w)(?!.*?<\/a>)/g,
    function($0, $1, $2) {
        return $1 ? $0 : '<a href="'+ window.location +'?q=' + $2 + '">#' + $2 + '</a>';
    }
));
```

This will match everything except other links.  See this [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/BWDRH3pBhLhpDu3BbZGc?p=preview).

Answer (score 5):

Try [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
var test = '#test is a #cool #place';
var html = test.replace(/#(\w+)/g, '<a href="abc.html?q=$1">#$1</a>')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
test = test.replace(/#([^ ]+)/g, '<a href="abc.html?q=$1">#$1</a>');
```